# Why Java compiler add "Redundant read" before "synchronized block"?

Tags: java, bytecode, synchronized

```
// the java source code
public class Demo {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void read() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // more code here ...
        }
    }
}

// the decompiled .class file
public class Demo {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void read() {
    // Why Java compiler add this line? Is the 'read this.lock' redundant?
    Object var1 = this.lock;
    synchronized(this.lock) {
        // more code here ...
    }
    }
}
```

**The bytecode here**: `javap -l -p -s demo.class`

```
public void read();
descriptor: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #3                  // Field lock:Ljava/lang/Object;
     4: dup
     5: astore_1
     6: monitorenter
     7: aload_1
     8: monitorexit
     9: goto          17
    12: astore_2
    13: aload_1
    14: monitorexit
    15: aload_2
    16: athrow
    17: return
  Exception table:
     from    to  target type
         7     9    12   any
        12    15    12   any
  LineNumberTable:
    line 15: 0
    line 16: 7
    line 17: 17
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      18     0  this   Lxechoz/vipshop/com/demo/thread/Demo;
  StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
    frame_type = 255 /* full_frame */
      offset_delta = 12
      locals = [ class xechoz/vipshop/com/demo/thread/Demo, class java/lang/Object ]
      stack = [ class java/lang/Throwable ]
    frame_type = 250 /* chop */
      offset_delta = 4
```

I think the line `1: getfield      #3                  // Field lock:Ljava/lang/Object;`

corresponds to `Object var1 = this.lock;`.

I know the compiler will optimize the code by adding or removing some code.

But, why the compiler add a **read** statement before the **synchronized block**.

Why this is needed? Or why it is an **optimization**?

Comment: Maybe worth to check the byte code directly. The decompiler may have some part in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the actual bytecodes.

```
  public void read();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #3                  // Field lock:Ljava/lang/Object;
       4: dup
       5: astore_1
       6: monitorenter
       7: aload_1
       8: monitorexit
       9: goto          17
      12: astore_2
      13: aload_1
      14: monitorexit
      15: aload_2
      16: athrow
      17: return
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           7     9    12   any
          12    15    12   any
```

You will see that there are two places where there `aload_1` is used to load the lock from the stack frame.

- The first time is when it is to be used as the operand for the monitorexit at offset 8.  That is the case where the code exits the synchronized block normally.
- The second time is when it is to be used as the operand for the monitorexit at offset 14.  That is the case where the code is unwinding a hypothetical<sup>1</sup> exception, where the monitor lock must be released before rethrowing the current exception.

(Also see @SubOptimal's pseudo-code.)

The bytecodes *could* be tightened up.  (For example, an optimizing bytecode compiler might realize that it could reload the lock from the `lock` field rather than a temporary variable.  However, that is only legitimate because `lock` is `final`!)

However ... the Java compiler strategy is NOT to optimize the bytecodes produced by `javac`.  Instead, the heavy duty optimization is done at JIT compilation time.  At that point, one would expect the native code to keep the lock in a register ... if that was the optimal thing to do.

---

The "extra variable" is probably an artifact of the decompiler that you are using.  It doesn't understand the idiom that the compiler uses.  It adds a local variable, without understanding that the variable is used in the synthetic handler block that it is hiding from you.

It is never wise to treat what a decompiler says as "truth".  It is well known that decompiled code can be misleading ... or not even valid Java code.

Certainly any observations on code optimization that are based solely on decompiler output are without merit.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, if consider `Thread.kill()` and the `ThreadDeath` exception that is used to implement it, it is not hypothetical.  Even for an empty block.</sup>

Comment: Actually, re-reading the field would require two instructions, `aload_0; getfield`, the second taking three bytes, having a total of four bytes, compared to the one byte of the sole `aload_1` instruction. In other words, even when counting the `dup; astore_1`, both having a size of one byte, using a local variable wins over re-reading the field, as soon as you have to access the value two times. And here, it is accessed at three places…

Comment: My real point is 1) the decompiled Java is misleading, 2) the bytecodes are explicable, and 3) **neither of them** have much to do how fast the *optimized native code* will perform.  Your observation is interesting, but doesn't contradict my "message".

Comment: It was not meant to be contradicting. You said correctly, “the Java compiler strategy is NOT to optimize the bytecodes”, but the preceding statement “the bytecodes could be tightened up” is not correct in this specific case, as it is already the most compact way of expressing that intent. My comment was not intended to create the impression of a fundamental flaw in your answer, as, besides that minor point addressed in my comment, everything is correct.

Answer (score 5):

From the [JLS 3.14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.14)

> Synchronization in the Java Virtual Machine is implemented by monitor entry and exit, either explicitly (by use of the monitorenter and monitorexit instructions) or implicitly (by the method invocation and return instructions).

To ensure that `monitorexit` is always executed the compiler adds an implicit `catch` clause for `Throwable`.

> To enforce proper pairing of monitorenter and monitorexit instructions on abrupt method invocation completion, the **compiler generates exception handlers** (§2.10) that will match any exception and whose associated code executes the necessary monitorexit instructions.

When using `javap -c Demo` you can see this addtional bytecode at offset 12-16

```
 0: aload_0
 1: getfield      #3                  // Field lock:Ljava/lang/Object;
 4: dup
 5: astore_1
 6: monitorenter
 7: aload_1 
 8: monitorexit
 9: goto          17
12: astore_2
13: aload_1
14: monitorexit
15: aload_2
16: athrow
17: return
Exception table:
     from    to  target type
         7     9    12   any
        12    15    12   any
```

The generated code as pseudo code

```
Object var1 = this.lock;
try {
   monitorenter(var1);
   // more code here ...
   monitorexit(var1);
} catch (Throwable t) {
   monitorexit(var1);
   throw t;
}
```

Comment: @StephenC You're right. This should not have been left out in the pseudo code.